# How to get variable on activity from BaseAdapter Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Im having a variable, `bill_id` on `MainActivity.` 
Then on `MainActivity`, I also has `list view` category, i put `onItemClick` on `CategoryListAdapter.` 
Here, when i click the category i want to reload the activity, which is `new intent`, and also pass variables, i want to pass `category_id` and `bill_id`(which is from `MainActivity`)

how can i get `bill_id` value from `BaseAdapter`?

here my snippet:

```
final int category_id = listData.get(position).getID();
        final String category_name = listData.get(position).get_name();

        holder.btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.d(TAG, "click category:"+category_id);
                Log.d(TAG, "category selected:"+category_name);

                // get cat id, reload with its id
                db = new DatabaseHelper(aContext);

                // bring variable id, to POS interface
                Intent intent = new Intent(aContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("category_id", category_id);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Im new to android programming, i dont understand how making intent can make me access the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple. Pass the values from your Activity to the Adapter using the adapter's constructor. This is what the constructors are for.

Like in your activity,

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(variable1, variable2);
```

Now in your adapter,

```
private int variable1, variable2;

// Constructor
public MyAdapter(int var1, int var2){
    this.variable1 = var1;
    this.variable2 = var2;
}
```

You can now easily use these variables in your click listener and pass them to the new intent.

You can also use setters for these variables in the adapter like,

```
public void setVariable1(int value){
    this.variable1 = value;
}

public void setVariable2(int value){
    this.variable2 = value;
}
```

And from your activity, do something like this whenever needed,

```
myAdapter.setVariable1(10);
```

So, these are the ways for you to access your variables from your activity inside your adapter.

Comment: Thank you! @AritraRoy. the solution work like a charms!